Empty `vec()` is not False
Consider this example:
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $vec0;

# set the first bit of vec0 to false
vec($vec0, 0, 1) = 0;

print "vec0 is " . length($vec0) . " bytes long\n";

if ($vec0) {
  # what
  print "vec0 is True!\n";
}

A vec used in evaluation seems to (almost) always be True - this is because a vec is really a string, and so $vec0 is a string containing "\0" which is not False according to Perl: only strings "" and "0" are False.
(aside: this is False, despite being non-zero:
vec($vec0, 5, 1) = 1;
vec($vec0, 4, 1) = 1;

because 0x30 is the ASCII code for 0)
Fine: what is the "correct" way to check for an "empty" vector (i.e. all bits set to 0)?  Count bits with unpack, regex test m/^\0*$/, "normalize" all vectors by chopping empty bytes off the end?  This seems like it should be a solved problem... and why does Perl not treat vec magically for true/false?

Can you state what precisely you consider "empty"?

if ( vec($vec0, 0, 1) )?

@zdim - All bits in the vector are unset (0)

Do you know the total number of bits you will be using? e.g. if you know there will be 8 bits in total, you can set individual bits like this: vec($vec0, 4, 1) = 1 # set bit 4 then to test if any of the 8 bits are set you check if (vec($vec0, 0, 8))

"All bits in the vector are unset (0)"  -- perhaps I don't get some part of what you're after, but if you convert it to a (bit)string with my $bits = unpack("b*", $vector); then in numeric context it will be equal to zero ($bits == 0) if all bits are unset.  I can't think of a more direct way, with vector itself

(Or, with $bits it's easy to check, bit by bit or against a mask of that many zero bits)

The following is probably the fastest approach without external C code:
$vec0 !~ tr/\x01-\xFF//   # True if "empty".

$vec0 =~ tr/\x01-\xFF//   # True if not "empty".


To check that

All bits in the vector are unset (0)

can convert it to a (bit)string with my $bits = unpack("b*", $vector) and then in numeric context that will be equal to zero ($bits == 0) if all bits are unset.  So
if ( unpack("b*", $vec0) == 0 ) { say "All bits zero" }

This is a shorthand of checking that no bits are set, ( unpack("b*", $vec0) | 0 ) == 0.
I don't think that vec has any "magical" way of checking for this.

If you're using fixed-width vectors, you can create another one of the appropriate length that's all-zeros and compare it with ones you want to test.
my $zero_vec = pack "C*", (0) x $length_in_bytes;

# ...

if ($vec0 ne $zero_vec) {
  print "vec0 is True!\n";
}

I also found an old module on CPAN, String::BitCount, that counts the number of set bits in a string:
use String::BitCount;

# ...

if (BitCount($vec0)) {
  print "vec0 is True!\n";
}

or maybe a regular expression:
if ($vec0 !~ m/\A\x00+\z/) {
  print "vec0 is True!\n";
}


pack "C*", (0) x $length_in_bytes simplifies to "\0" x $length_in_bytes
